# Sorting an array of hashes by a date field

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have an object with many arrays of hashes, one of which I want to sort by a value in the 'date' key.

```
 @array['info'][0] = {"name"=>"personA", "date"=>"23/09/1980"}
 @array['info'][1] = {"name"=>"personB", "date"=>"01/04/1970"}
 @array['info'][2] = {"name"=>"personC", "date"=>"03/04/1975"}
```

I have tried various methods using Date.parse and with collect but an unable to find a good solution.

**Edit:**
 To be clear I want to sort the original array in place

```
    @array['info'].sort_by { |i| Date.parse i['date'] }.collect
```

How might one solve this elegantly the 'Ruby-ist' way. Thanks

Comment: What isn't working about the above?  Just drop the `.collect` and if you want to modify it in place add `!` to `sort_by`.

Comment: I think this is one of those posts where the OP already has working code and wants to know if there is a more elegant way, but the OP should try harder to make that clear to the readers.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipHallstrom, that did it. I am slightly confused though as my original attempt did not reorder the original array but it sounds like it should have?

Comment: Your original attempt uses `sort_by` which does not modify the original array.  That's why he recommended you use `sort_by!` instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I must read up on the documentation. I presume that my use of collect here was not correct here in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way, which doesn't require converting the date strings to date objects, is the following.

**Code**

```
def sort_by_date(arr)
  arr.sort_by { |h| h["date"].split('/').reverse }
end
```

If `arr` is to be sorted in place, use [Array#sort_by!](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) rather than [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

**Example**

```
arr = [{ "name"=>"personA", "date"=>"23/09/1980" },
       { "name"=>"personB", "date"=>"01/04/1970" },
       { "name"=>"personC", "date"=>"03/04/1975" }]

sort_by_date(arr)
  #=> [{ "name"=>"personB", "date"=>"01/04/1970" },
  #    { "name"=>"personC", "date"=>"03/04/1975" },
  #    { "name"=>"personA", "date"=>"23/09/1980" }]
```

**Explanation**

For `arr` in the example, `sort_by` passes the first element of `arr` into its block and assigns it to the block variable:

```
h = { "name"=>"personA", "date"=>"23/09/1980" }
```

then computes:

```
a = h["date"].split('/')
  #=> ["23", "09", "1980"]
```

and then:

```
b = a.reverse
  #=> ["1980", "09", "23"]
```

Similarly, we obtain `b` equal to:

```
["1970", "04", "01"]
```

and

```
["1975", "04", "03"]
```

for each of the other two elements of `arr`.

If you look at the docs for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) you will see that these three arrays are ordered as follows:

```
["1970", "04", "01"] < ["1975", "04", "03"] < ["1980", "09", "23"]
```

There is no need to convert the string elements to integers.

Comment: I know i am late, but can anyone resolve it for me? My dates are like this #<Date: 2018-04-04 ((2458213j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>. So I am getting this error: undefined method `split' for #<Date: 2018-04-04 ((2458213j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Answer (score 5):

Looks fine overall.  Although you can drop the `collect` call since it's not needed and use [`sort_by!`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) to modify the array in-place (instead of reassigning):

```ruby
@array['info'].sort_by! { |x| Date.parse x['date'] }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have obviously misunderstood but I thought that collect would have done this for me and I wouldn't have needed sort_by!